# Creating a Textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create large number of textboxes with loop. lets say I want to create one textbox and I tried this code ;

```
        UserForm1.Controls.Add "Forms.TextBox.1", "Txt", True
```

with this code I can create textbox but I can't reach the properties of textbox .For example When I try this ;

```
UserForm1.Controls.Add "Forms.TextBox.1", "Txt", True
UserForm1.txt.Text = "asdasd"
```

It gives "compile error. Method or Data member not found". How can I reach the properties of this textbox?

Comment: So you have several textboxes all with the same name? Try giving them different names by using <"Txt" & i> as the name, where <i> would increment at each loop. That was you would be able to refer to them seperately. I don't know if that's the source of the error, but you should do it either way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I'am doing it just like you said .  , My code in the loop is UserForm1.Controls.Add "Forms.TextBox.1", "Txt" & x & y, True    but I think If i can solve how to reach just one of them I can modify all .thats why I didn't write the whole code

Comment: Have you tried this syntax? UserForm1.Controls("Txt" & x & y).Value = "abcde"

Comment: Now I tried . but not worked

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592641/assign-event-handlers-to-controls-on-user-form-created-dynamically-in-vba/10596866#10596866.  That approach sets an object equal to the newly added control.  You then have access to its properties at compile time.  The advice by @DavidGM should work, so please [edit] your question with what you tried and an explanation of `not worked`.

Comment: Also `it gives an error` is not an adequate description. Please provide the exact error.  I suspect it was a compile time error because that property does not exist at compile time since the compiler does not know you are creating the object.  Instead of letting us assume that, please [edit] those details into your question.

Comment: Thanks for the warning , I edited the question like you said.

Comment: What happens when you use the syntax suggested by @DavidGM?  You should be able to go through `UserForm1.Controls("object name")`.  Did you try the other approach in the link I provided?  That is create an object and `Set` when you add it.

Comment: When I use @DavidGM's syntax I'm encountering Method or Data member not found error. I work it out with the link you send. Thanks for the help guys.I appreciate it.