# How to reference generated VBA Userform Controls?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am currently recreating an [HSV Colorpicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlU9B.png) (as template for other colorspaces) as a Excel VBA userform. All controls are generated on start and successfully added the controls to separate class modules for one to the other (in this project's case, the colorpicker controls and the hue controls).

However I am struggling to find a way to refer to the generated controls at the class modules. Once the click event that I program on the class module starts, I do not know how it will reference the generated controls at all. On my current case, I need the hue controls to refer to the colorpicker controls and change their colors according to its hue. But so far it seems that the class module cannot see them.

Here is the userform code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim PixelArray() As New Class1
Dim Pixel(0 To 100, 0 To 100) As MSForms.Image

Dim HueArray() As New Class2
Dim Huebutton(0 To 360) As MSForms.Image

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim R As Double, G As Double, B As Double, H As Double, S As Double, V As Double, C As Double, Y As Double, PCV As Double, YType As String, WithinGamut As Boolean
    ReDim Preserve PixelArray(0 To 100, 0 To 100)
    ReDim Preserve HueArray(0 To 360)
    
    YType = "Y601"
    'Colorpicker
    H = 0
    For j = 0 To 100
    For i = 0 To 100
        S = i / 100
        V = j / 100
        Call HSVColorPicker(R, G, B, H, S, V, C, Y, PCV, YType, WithinGamut) 'Formula
        Set Pixel(i, j) = Me.Colorpicker.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1")
        With Pixel(i, j)
                .Width = 3
                .Height = 3
                .Left = 6 + 3 * i
                .Top = 6 + 3 * (100 - j)
                .BackColor = RGB(R * 255, G * 255, B * 255)
                .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
        End With
        Set PixelArray(i, j).clickEvent = Pixel(i, j)
    Next i
    Next j

    
    ' Hue Column
        YType = "Y601"
        S = 1
        V = 1
    For k = 0 To 360
        H = k
        Call HSVColorPicker(R, G, B, H, S, V, C, Y, PCV, YType, WithinGamut) ' Will replace later
        Set Huebutton(k) = Me.Hue.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1")
        With Huebutton(k)
                .Width = 12
                .Height = 2
                .Left = 6
                .Top = 6 + 1 * k
                .BackColor = RGB(R * 255, G * 255, B * 255)
                .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
        End With
        Set HueArray(k).hueEvent = Huebutton(k)
    Next k
    
End Sub
```

And here is the code for the Class modules for the colorpicker

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents clickEvent As MSForms.Image

Private Sub clickEvent_click()

    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = clickEvent.BackColor

End Sub
```

Next code is the class module for the Hue Bar and I need this to be able to refer to the controls of the generated controls.

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents hueEvent As MSForms.Image

Private Sub hueEvent_click()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim R As Double, G As Double, B As Double, H As Double, S As Double, V As Double, C As Double, Y As Double, PCV As Double, YType As String, WithinGamut As Boolean
    
    H = 240
    YType = "Y601"
    For i = 0 To 100
    For j = 0 To 100
        S = i / 100
        V = j / 100
        Call HSVColorPicker(R, G, B, H, S, V, C, Y, PCV, YType, WithinGamut)
        With Colorpicker.Colorpicker.Pixel(i, j)
                .BackColor = RGB(R * 255, G * 255, B * 255)
        End With
    Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You may find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407974/dynamically-define-the-events-of-the-checkboxes-in-vba

Comment: I don't follow which controls need to refer to other controls and why, but for whatever reason they can refer back to the form and then the class references where each control is stored. In passing, and if I follow, you're applying a grid of Image controls each to store a graduated HSL(v) colour from which to 'pick', yikes! Why not use Excel's built in color picker...

Comment: @PeterT Can you elaborate on the first sentence? I tried referring back to the userform itself on the last class module with this line of code 'With Colorpicker.Colorpicker.Pixel(i, j)' but that line is the only thing so far that gives me error. Also, yes it is currently slow right now but I need something like this to actually do a colorpicker for other colorspaces like CIELab. Need to make something work first before I can make something efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid I still don't follow your objective here though whatever it is I suspect there are better ways, but some ideas to get your classes and form talking to each other...

```
''''''''''''''' UserForm1 ''''''''''''''
Option Explicit
Private mCls As Class1
Private msData(1 To 100) As String

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Long
Dim cbt As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim id As Long
    id = 50
    msData(id) = "Apple"
    
    Set mCls = New Class1
    Call mCls.Init(id, Me)
    
    Set mCls.Button = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
    With mCls.Button
        .Left = 30: .Top = 30
        .Width = 90: .Height = 24
        .Caption = "Button " & id
    End With

End Sub

Friend Sub Hello(sMsg)
    MsgBox sMsg
End Sub

Friend Property Get data(idx) As String
    data = msData(idx)
End Property
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

''''''''''' Class1 '''''''''''''
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents mBtn As MSForms.CommandButton
Private mParent As UserForm1
Private mlID As Long

Friend Sub Init(id As Long, UF As UserForm1)
    mlID = id
    Set mParent = UF
End Sub

Friend Property Set Button(btn As MSForms.CommandButton)
    Set mBtn = btn
End Property

Friend Property Get Button() As MSForms.CommandButton
    Set Button = mBtn
End Property

Private Sub mBtn_Click()
Dim sData As String

    sData = mParent.data(mlID)
    mParent.Hello "Hi from button " & mlID & vbNewLine _
                    & "Data: " & sData

End Sub
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```