# Excel VBA: how to cast a control got from the UserForm's Controls collection to its native ActiveX type?

Tags: vba, excel, casting, controls, activex

We are using a 3rd-party ActiveX grid control [10Tec iGrid](https://10tec.com/activex-grid/) in an Excel 2016 VBA application on a UserForm. We need to retrieve this control by the string name generated dynamically and cast it to its native type for further operations.

This is very easy to do for intrinsic MSForms types like CommandButton, for example:

```vbs
Dim cmdbtn As iGrid
Set cmdbtn = Me.Controls("cmdOk")
```

However, this approach does not work for iGrid:

```vbs
Dim grid As iGrid
Set grid = Me.Controls("iGrid1")
```

We always get the

> Type mismatch

error.

This also does not help (the same problem):

```vbs
Dim grid As iGrid
Set grid = Me.Controls("iGrid1").Object
```

Is there a way to get an ActiveX control in its native type dynamically by its string name in VBA UserForms?

Comment: Does `Set grid = Me.iGrid1` have the same problem?

Comment: @Rory, This is strange, but I have the same Type mismatch problem even for this statement. What can be the source of this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the only VBA snippet in their own online library simply uses `Control` as the type.

Comment: If you want to set a control to a specific type for the inbuilt types you usually refer to the library that holds them:
Dim MyBox as MsForms.TextBox
Do you need to do that for your iGrid?

Comment: @HarassedDad, there is no difference even if I fully qualify the type like `Dim grid As iGrid650_10Tec.iGrid` - because VBA can identify this iGrid type without any collisions with other libraries. Needless to mention that the link to the type library containing the iGrid types is also checked in the Tools\References dialog in VBA.

Comment: It works if you define grid as type object correct?

Comment: @KacireeSoftware, sorry, didn't understand. Can you explain what you meant?

Comment: @tecman sorry man im at the deer lease. What i mean is if you declare the variable as Object does the code complain? 'Dim Grid as Object' 'Set Grid = Controls("iGrid1")'

Comment: @KacireeSoftware, we need the native iGrid type to attach event handlers dynamically like in SWa's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592641/assign-event-handlers-to-controls-on-user-form-created-dynamically-in-vba) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public iGridData As Control
Set iGridData = UserForm1.Controls.Add("iGrid700_10Tec.iGrid", "iGridName", True)
```