# Creating a Dynamic CheckBox Variable

Tags: excel, vba, controls, userform

I created a userform that is populated with checkboxes based off of the cell values on multiple worksheets. I named the checkboxes based off of the cell values (none of them are the same) but the number of cells will change over time so I wanted to have a code populate the userform rather than manually put each checkbox in. I want to be able to call on specific cell value information if its checkbox is clicked but my code isn't working. I think I need to create a dynamic checkbox variable that changes each time. I'm currently unable to call on any of the checkboxes except the very last one.

```
    Public chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox

    Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    MemNumCombo.Clear

    Dim o As Long
    Dim chkL As Double
    Dim chkT As Double
    Dim chkH As Double
    Dim chkW As Double

    chkL = 125
    chkT = 5
    chkH = 15
    chkW = 80

    o = 2
    Do Until Worksheets("Operations").Cells(o, 1).Value = "Division:"

        Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", Worksheets("Operations").Cells(o, 1).Value & Worksheets("Operations").Cells(o, 3).Value & "Check")

        chkBox.Caption = Worksheets("Operations").Cells(o, 1).Value & " " & Worksheets("Operations").Cells(o, 3).Value

        chkBox.Left = chkL
        chkBox.Top = chkT + (o - 1) * 20
        chkBox.Height = chkH
        chkBox.Width = chkW

        o = o + 1
    Loop

'...
   End Sub
```

I know when the code runs the chkBox's name is correct but I can't call on the chkBox by it's name later on. When the code is done running, I can only call on the last chkBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Can't) call the chkBox by it's name...**

You set the `chkBox` object to memory in a loop thus overwriting one check box by the next one; referring to the variable alone via `chkBox` or `chkBox.Value` somewhere after in code will return (the set object itself or e.g. the value of) the *last* checkbox.

**Calling CheckBoxes via the `Controls` Collection**

Using the `Controls.Add` method via `Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", Worksheets("Operations").Cells(o, 1).Value & Worksheets("Operations").Cells(o, 3).Value & "Check")` you already defined names (concatenated from two columns in worksheet "Operations" plus the Suffix "Check").

You can call a checkbox by one of these names via the `Controls` collection; assuming one of your check boxes actually got named `"XY47Check"` you address it via `Me.Controls("XY47Check")`.

**Listing Checkbox names**

A very simple and helpful approach consists in assigning all checkbox names to an *Array* you can address by indices in the predefined sheet order.

Simply `[1]` declare a variant array `Dim ChkNames()` in the *declaration head* of your userform code module, `[2]` add the calling code line

```
    FillChkNames
```

to your `Userform_Initialize` procedure as well as `[3]` the following helper procedure `Sub FillChkNames()` to your Userform module:

```
Private Sub FillChkNames()
' Purpose: populate array ChkNames at userform module level
ReDim ChkNames(Me.Controls.Count - 1)
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control, i&
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then ChkNames(i) = ctl.Name: i = i + 1
    Debug.Print ctl.Name, ctl.Value, TypeName(ctl)
Next ctl
ReDim Preserve ChkNames(i - 1)

End Sub
```

This allows you to get all checkboxes by name

**Some example calls anywhere within the userform code module**

```
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' List all combo names in array
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Debug.Print Join(ChkNames, "|")
' List all combo names plus values
  Dim chkName As Variant
  For Each chkName In ChkNames
      Debug.Print chkName, Me.Controls(chkName)
  Next chkName

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' List single value - e.g. the third check box in array
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Dim myNum As Long: myNum = 2                          ' zero-based index 2 refers to third item in array
  If myNum <= UBound(ChkNames) Then
      Debug.Print "Index no " & myNum & " ~> Value: " & Me.Controls(ChkNames(myNum))
  Else
      Debug.Print "Invalid index :-(" & myNum & ")"
  End If
```

**Advanced methods**

Alternatively you can use a *collection of objects* instead of a single object and study other numerous examples at SO using classes, e.g. at [assign event handlers to controls on userform created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592641/assign-event-handlers-to-controls-on-user-form-created-dynamically-in-vba)